# AutoComplete can't be found in new compatibility library and Gives Program Type Already Present With New Places Library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, google-places-api

I was trying to add an AutoComplete feature while letting user select a place. I followed [the official documents](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) and implemented the feature. But if I just use the compatibility library  `('com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0')` and don't use the new places library `('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0')` I cannot import anything useful related to AutoComplete.(only 4 classes from widget which are not useful for coding and I believe they cause the program type already present error when I include the new places library)

To start auto complete I use this code

```
 val fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID,
                Place.Field.NAME,
                Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                Place.Field.ADDRESS_COMPONENTS,
                Place.Field.LAT_LNG,
                Place.Field.OPENING_HOURS,
                Place.Field.PHONE_NUMBER,
                Place.Field.PRICE_LEVEL,
                Place.Field.RATING,
                Place.Field.TYPES,
                Place.Field.PHOTO_METADATAS,
                Place.Field.TYPES,
                Place.Field.VIEWPORT,
                Place.Field.USER_RATINGS_TOTAL)

        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                .build(this@AddPartnerActivity)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)//Request code is just a number
    }
```

Android doesn't suggest me any useful import while new places library is missing.When I use exclude in gradle `Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity`is not fixed. I can also paste my gradle file for your reference (it's a mess and I tried to write exclude into any import that can possibly create a problem). One important thing to note is code was working fine without adding the new places api if I don't use autocomplete.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.libraries.places.widget'
    }




    //Ion
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'

    //Facebook Login
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.41.0'

    //Google Login
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    //Anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

    // Anko Layout
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"



    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'

    //PlaceholderView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3'
    kapt 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview-compiler:1.0.3'


    //Web Sockets
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.3'

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    //Firebase Cloud Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.5.0'



    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'


    //Firebase Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'

    //Map Utility
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'



    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation ('com.schibstedspain.android:leku:6.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
        exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.libraries.places.widget'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.libraries.places.widget'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0')

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Note that you cannot install both the compatibility library and the new client library. Can you use the client library only? Try following the get started guides [1](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) [2](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity) and using Google's exact code, please let us know if the issue persists even after doing so.

Comment: Client library and compatibility library features different kind of attributes for the object "Place" (for example I couldn't get opening hours when I use the compatibility library, and some things I could get with compatibility library, I couldn't get with new api (maybe that's my bad) I found my mistake in the code, I am posting the solution

Comment: I  wrote my solution to the question. I would be more than happy if you can comment on it if I am wrong in some part, and about the billing. Because with new library I can just get opening hours directly without sending any additional http request which seems to be cheaper. This is important since I will let my users, use this feature

Comment: Hey glad to hear you were able to fix this, although the compatibility library is just meant to help you migrate to the new SDK client (hence all its limitations). You should still install the client library. i.e `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0` + AndroidX migration asap.

Comment: As for billing, as long as you only request Basic Data SKU fields you won't be extra charged (opening hours is a basic data field yes) but you may still be billed for the places detail + autocomplete call. It's explained in this doc please do read it carefully: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing

Answer (score 0):

My first mistake was that in compatibility library, I should use the `Place` prefix with AutoComplete to find the necessary imports.

```
   val intent = PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this@AddPartnerActivity)
```

Second issue was that I wanted to get the property `opening_hours`(and data about photos) from `Place`object which was present in new places library, but not present in compatibility library. In compatibility library to retrieve this, one should send a query instead of creating a list of types he wants to retrieve directly from the place object like I did in the question.
Basically one should sent a request to this url using the id retrieved from autocomplete. Documentation for this can be found here [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)

```
val url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=$placeId&fields=opening_hours,photos,reviews&key=YOUR_API_KEY" //place id is the id of the place you got from autocomplete
```

My confusion came from the fact that you need to send a query in one library which I thnk is subject to billing while in the new api you can directly retrieve the opening hours.